# How to insert spaces between components in Ext js 4 layout

Tags: extjs

I'm moving from adobe flex to ext js 4, and I noted that in Extjs, the components are placed too close. There is no gap between then. This can be faced with this example:

```
    var win = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
    layout: 'hbox',
    height: 500,
    width: 400,
    title: 'hbox',      
    items: [
      Ext.create('Ext.button.Button',
      {
        text: 'My button 1',
        width: 150
      }),
      Ext.create('Ext.button.Button',
      {
        text: 'My button 2',
        width: 150
      })
    ]
});

win.show();
```

The two button are zero space from each other.

How to set a space (gap or ever) from components?

Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use the margin config:

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
    var win = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
        layout: 'hbox',
        height: 500,
        width: 400,
        autoShow: true,
        title: 'hbox',
        defaultType: 'button',
        items: [{
            text: 'My button 1',
            width: 150,
            margin: '10 20 30 40'
        }, {
            text: 'My button 2',
            width: 150,
            margin: '40 30 20 10'
        }]
    });
});
```

Comment: To save you looking this up the margin values correspond to top, right, bottom, left so "10 0 0 0" will create a margin of 10 px at the top only.

Comment: If you want the same margin for all children, add a `defaults` property to the parent `defaults: { margin:'0 15 0 0' }`. This makes more sense in a column layout for example.

Answer (score 2):

like a margin ? 
You can add that by the style atttribute. See this ex http://jsfiddle.net/nscrob/5rn8C/5/

Comment: It works. And also works using defaults: {margin: 2} in the window parameters. Thanks.